# Orthogonal projection onto a subvector space of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Consider the subvectorspace $K\subset L^2(\mathbb{R})$ defined as

$$K=\left\{f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}) | \forall n\in\mathbb{Z}:\int_n^{n+1}f(x)=0\right\}.$$

I'm trying to find the orthogonal projection $p_K:L^2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow K$.

I know I can find $p_K$ by finding an orthonormal basis $(e_k)_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$, for $K$. Since $K$ is closed we hopefully can conclude that $K=\text{closure(span}\{e_k|k\in\mathbb{Z}\})$ (I will not state a proof here). Then, for every $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we would have
$$p_K(f)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\langle f,e_k\rangle e_k.$$

I found an orthonormal set $(e_k)_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ where $e_k:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}:x\mapsto e^{2\pi ixk}\chi_{[k,k+1]}(x)$. It is easy to check that this set is indeed orthonormal.

I now claim that this set is maximal orthonormal in $K$, meaning that if for $f\in K$ we have that $\langle f,e_k\rangle=0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $f=0$. Take an $f\in K$ such that $\langle f,e_k\rangle=0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and consider the inner product:

$$\langle f,e_k\rangle = \int_\mathbb{R}f(x)e^{-2\pi ikx}\chi_{[k,k+1]}(x)dx=0.$$

Define the functions $h_k:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}:x\mapsto f(x)\chi_{[k,k+1]}(x)$. We then get $\langle f,e_k\rangle=\widehat{h_k}(k)=0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, where $\widehat{h_k}$ denotes the Fouriertransform of $h_k$. Since the Fouriertransform of $h_k$ is always $0$ we find that $h_k$ is zero almost everywhere. Now $f=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}h_k}$ so $f$ is zero almost everywhere and thus $f=0$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

So $\text{span}\{e_k|k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $K$ meaning for every $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ the orthogonal projection onto $K$ is given by

$$p_K(f)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\langle f,e_k\rangle e_k,$$

where $e_k(x)=e^{2\pi ikx}\chi_{[k,k+1]}(x)$ and $\langle f,e_k\rangle=\int_k^{k+1}f(x)e^{-2\pi ikx}dx$.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: This looks good to me. Another choice could have been generated from the Haar wavelet on $[0,1]$ and then shifted accordingly.